# Opentelemetry & Jaeger error SEVERE: Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Failed to connect to http://simplest-collector:4317

Tags: yaml, openshift, open-telemetry, jaeger, exporter

I've configured 2 simplest yamls to deploy on Openshift with my application.

- My jaeger yml :

```
apiVersion: jaegertracing.io/v1
kind: Jaeger
metadata:
  name: my-jaeger
```

- My collector yml:

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: simplest
  namespace: opentelemetry-project
spec:
  mode: deployment
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:
    processors:
    exporters:
      jaeger:
        endpoint: my-jaeger-collector-headless.opentelemetry-project.svc:14250
        tls:
          ca_file: "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt"
    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [jaeger]
```

My application code to export the spans :

```
  String jaegerEndpoint =  String jaegerEndpoint= "http://my-jaeger-collector-opentelemetry-project.apps.ocp12.my.cluster";  **//What would be the correct endpoint to my jaeger instance on openshift?**
    Resource serviceNameResource = Resource.getDefault()
      .merge(Resource.create(Attributes.of(ResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME, "test-traced-service")));
    // Export traces to Jaeger over OTLP
    OtlpGrpcSpanExporter jaegerOtlpExporter =
      OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.builder()
        .setEndpoint(jaegerEndpoint)
        .setTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();


    // Set to process the spans by the Jaeger Exporter
    SdkTracerProvider tracerProvider =
      SdkTracerProvider.builder()
        .addSpanProcessor(BatchSpanProcessor.builder(jaegerOtlpExporter).build())
        .setResource(Resource.getDefault().merge(serviceNameResource))
        .build();

    OpenTelemetrySdk openTelemetry =
      OpenTelemetrySdk.builder().setTracerProvider(tracerProvider).build();

    // it's always a good idea to shut down the SDK cleanly at JVM exit.
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(tracerProvider::close));

    vertx = Vertx.vertx( new VertxOptions()
                           .setTracingOptions(new OpenTelemetryOptions(openTelemetry)));

    Tracer tracer = openTelemetry.getTracer("io.vertx");

    Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("another span use case").startSpan();
    span.setAttribute("attribute3", "I am the attribute3");
    span.addEvent("Event 3");
    Thread.sleep(800);
    span.addEvent("Event 4");
    span.end();
```

My logs :

```
2023/04/10 10:23:36 provider.go:129: Defaulting client-id to system:serviceaccount:opentelemetry-project:my-jaeger-ui-proxy
2023/04/10 10:23:36 provider.go:134: Defaulting client-secret to service account token /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
2023/04/10 10:23:36 oauthproxy.go:203: mapping path "/" => upstream "http://localhost:16686/"
2023/04/10 10:23:36 oauthproxy.go:230: OAuthProxy configured for  Client ID: system:serviceaccount:opentelemetry-project:my-jaeger-ui-proxy
2023/04/10 10:23:36 oauthproxy.go:240: Cookie settings: name:_oauth_proxy secure(https):true httponly:true expiry:168h0m0s domain:<default> samesite: refresh:disabled
2023/04/10 10:23:36 http.go:61: HTTP: listening on 127.0.0.1:4180
2023/04/10 10:23:36 http.go:107: HTTPS: listening on [::]:8443
I0410 10:23:36.015642       1 dynamic_serving_content.go:130] Starting serving::/etc/tls/private/tls.crt::/etc/tls/private/tls.key
```

```
2023-04-10T10:23:41.499Z    info    service/telemetry.go:110    Setting up own telemetry...
2023-04-10T10:23:41.499Z    info    service/telemetry.go:140    Serving Prometheus metrics  {"address": ":8888", "level": "basic"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    service/service.go:89   Starting otelcol... {"Version": "0.63.1", "NumCPU": 4}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    extensions/extensions.go:42 Starting extensions...
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    pipelines/pipelines.go:74   Starting exporters...
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    pipelines/pipelines.go:78   Exporter is starting... {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    jaegerexporter@v0.63.0/exporter.go:185  State of the connection with the Jaeger Collector backend   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger", "state": "IDLE"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    pipelines/pipelines.go:82   Exporter started.   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    pipelines/pipelines.go:86   Starting processors...
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    pipelines/pipelines.go:98   Starting receivers...
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    pipelines/pipelines.go:102  Receiver is starting... {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    otlpreceiver/otlp.go:71 Starting GRPC server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "traces", "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4317"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    otlpreceiver/otlp.go:89 Starting HTTP server    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "traces", "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4318"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    pipelines/pipelines.go:106  Receiver started.   {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "pipeline": "traces"}
2023-04-10T10:23:41.500Z    info    service/service.go:106  Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
2023-04-10T10:23:42.500Z    info    jaegerexporter@v0.63.0/exporter.go:185  State of the connection with the Jaeger Collector backend   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "jaeger", "state": "READY"}
```

And the error that I got:
**SEVERE: Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to http://simplest-collector:4317**

What would be the correct endpoint for my jaeger instance on openshift? or what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try having a look here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/issues/5309#issuecomment-1146219741

Comment: I already checked that post before I wrote my question here, that was not very helpful, but thanks. I would need to know what's the correct jaeger endpoint when we use a openshift cluster, but neither works this from openshift documentation :
 jaeger:
        endpoint: my-jaeger-collector-headless.opentelemetry-project.svc:14250
         
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/distr_tracing/distr_tracing_install/distr-tracing-deploying-otel.html

Comment: I've edited my post to try to be more clear on my question, thanks!